# How to change default web page to open in browser

Tags: iceweasel

I don't know and don't think that this is the right place to ask this question, but I don't know where else to ask this question.

When I open my browser IceWeasel, it used to open a default webpage that was stored locally on my system. However, now, it seems that for some reason, the default file address for the .html file has changed, so it attempts to open a file that does not exist. How can I fix this so that it opens the correct file on the correct file path?

Comment: you mean `homepage`?

Comment: Sure. The webpage opened up on startup. I don't call it homepage.

Comment: Kali Linux is off-topic here. Ask on [unix.se].

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic (ref:[here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/686783/how-to-change-default-web-page-to-open-in-browser/686824#comment1000899_686824))

Comment: Ok, I don't know where to ask Kali Linux questions. Thank you.

Comment: (sorry) I think ypu can ask in  http://superuser.com/

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so Kali is off-topic here as well.** However, on [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, especially if you use the *Kali-Linux* tag.  **;-)**
CC: @Ravan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just found out how to do it. It is in General when opening up the Preferences. It's one of the first options.

Answer (score 0):

- Open **Ice Weasel.**
- Go to **Tools** and click on **Options..**
- In the Main section type the homepage you want and click **OK** at the bottom.

<sub>reference [here](http://www.microcentertech.com/tech_center/DB/read_article.php?faqid=./HowTos/HOW5007411B.htm)</sub>

Comment: This is on Kali Linux, and the site you referenced is on windows. I don't see any option for **Tools**. Where can I find it?